how to create a generic tsx function to load all my components with suspence fallback null with generic type
how can we create a generic functional component in react with tsx to load routes component with suspense fallback null


import React, { Suspense } from "react";

const WithSuspense = (LazyComponent: React.LazyExoticComponent<any>) => {
  return (props: any) => (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <LazyComponent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default WithSuspense;




The issue is the lack of proper type safety in the WithSuspense function. Here's the fixed and fully generic version:
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

type WithSuspenseProps<T> = T & { children?: React.ReactNode };

const WithSuspense = <T,>(LazyComponent: React.LazyExoticComponent<React.ComponentType<T>>) => {
  return (props: WithSuspenseProps<T>) => (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <LazyComponent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default WithSuspense;

This solution ensures type safety and works generically with all lazy-loaded components.

Type 'WithSuspenseProps' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((PropsWithoutRef & RefAttributes<Component<T, any, any>>) | PropsWithRef)'.
Type 'WithSuspenseProps' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithRef'.
Type 'WithSuspenseProps' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithRef'.ts(2322)
